# Getting a field value using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Can I get the value of the field which I am not showing in form? I want to pass ref_id in session.
This is my model:

```
  def _createId():
        """
        """
        return hexlify(os.urandom(4))

class jobpost(models.Model):
    item_types = (
        ('Full Time','Full Time'),
        ('Part Time','Part Time'),
        ('Contract','Contract'),
    )
    posttype= (
        ('Job','Job'),
        ('Classified','Classified'),
        ('Project/Task','Project/Task'),
        ('Internship','Internship'),
    )
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    job_id =             models.AutoField(primary_key=True)   
    country= models.ForeignKey(Country,to_field = 'country_name',  null=True)
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable = False)
    post_type =        models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, choices=posttype,default='Job')
    job_type =        models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, choices=item_types,default='Full Time')
    job_location =    models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    job_title =             models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    job_description =       models.TextField(null=True)
    start_date =    models.DateField(null=True, help_text="mm/dd/yyyy")
    end_date =      models.DateField(null=True, help_text="mm/dd/yyyy")
    how_to_apply =    models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    ref_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=_createId)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.country)
        return self.post_type
        return self.job_location
        return self.job_type
        return self.job_title
        return self.job_description
        return self.start_date 
        return self.end_date
        return self.how_to_apply
        return self.ref_id
```

means i am not displaying it in my form and i want to pass this value in session in next form..
can anyone tell me how can i do this? and how can i pass the primary key of the form in next form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forms.py

```
class JobPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JobPostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['ref_id'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    class Meta:
        model = jobpost
```

views.py

```
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = JobPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['ref_id'] = form.cleaned_data.get('ref_id')
            pk = form.save()
            request.session['pk'] = pk.id
    else:
        form = JobPostForm()
    return render(request, page.html,{'form': form})
```

Comment: `form.cleaned_data.get('ref_id')`

Comment: answer updated, sorry I forgot I'm passing it to session variable

Comment: Thanku so very much :)..can u plz also tell me how can i pass the pk through session to next form?

Comment: can u give me the ans of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895449/performing-different-functionality-on-modelform-buttons-django