# performing different functionality on modelform buttons django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a modelform with 2 buttons and i want to perform different functionality on them.
My modelform:

```
class jobpostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:

        model = jobpost
        fields = ('job_title','job_type','job_location','job_description','start_date','end_date','country','how_to_apply')

    widgets = {

        'job_type':RadioSelect(),    
        'job_location':TextInput(attrs={'size':'70'}),   
        'job_description':Textarea(attrs={'cols':200, 'rows':10}),
            'start_date':TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'datepicker',
                'data-date-format': 'mm/dd/yyyy', 

            }),
            'end_date':TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'datepicker',
                'data-date-format': 'mm/dd/yyyy', 
            }),

    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #super(jobpostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.fields['start_date'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'datepicker'
        super(jobpostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.fields['ref_id'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'horizontal-form'
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-jobpostform'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'

        self.helper.form_action = '/portal/next/post/'

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit_addcontent', 'Preview'))
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit_addcontent', 'Submit'))


        super(jobpostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I want to perform different functionality on submit and preview.How can i access them in my view?

Comment: I never tried this one, where did you learn this?

Comment: check this https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/tags.html

Comment: ah, ok...I thought it's a built-in functions in Django. It's from a third-party app. Ever since, I never use third party app in my project. I stick to django...

Answer (score 0):

A django form really handles two things:

- Displaying the intitial form on a GET request
- Processing POST requests with data

You can approach your situation in multiple ways. One way would be to have both buttons submit your form. The preview button would fill in a hidden field named `preview`. Your form would process the submitted data. If the data included a value in the POST field named `preview` it would render a preview. Otherwise, it would process the form normally.

Comment: is there any way to check which button is clicked?

Comment: Yes. The `preview` button would fill in a hidden field named `preview` with a value `1`. Your form could check if the value of the POST param named `preview` is `1` and if it is process the preview. Otherwise, process the submit.